# Is it OK to define an overloaded function?

Tags: discussion, rules

Sometimes it would be quite useful in some languages to define two overloaded functions/methods as one answer. That is, instead of doing this (using Java as an example):

```
int f(Object o){if (o instanceof Integer) ... else if (o instanceof String) ...}
```

You would do this:

```
int f(Integer i){...}
int f(String s) {...}
```

In case of Java, you don't have to change to call site, but I'm not sure if this applies to all languages.

Comment: Do you have an example of an existing question where you need to do this? If not, please avoid asking about unlikely hypothetical scenarios.

Comment: This is common practice in Mathematica (although overloading semantics are a bit different there, but the effect is basically the same).

Comment: @feersum I'm asking because of [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/94832) challenge.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, that's perfectly fine.

I could see this being useful for the [recent challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/94832/45941) that requires different outputs based on if the input is an integer or a float/decimal.

Comment: Yes, I had that exact question in mind.